# Перенос JSON из API Stack OferFlow на jetty-server

Tags: json, парсер, gson, jetty

Я только учусь программированию и нигде не могу нагуглить свою проблему. Дело в том, что у меня есть необходимость перенести полученный JSON из API Stack OverFlow в строку, чтобы потом вытащить из неё при помощи GSON структурированные данные на веб-сервер jetty.
Ошибка вылетает либо при добавлении в StringBuilder с проблемами с кодировкой и её кракозябрами, либо ошибка 500 от Gson. Не подскажите что я делаю не так?

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                   HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> pageVariables = createPageVariablesMap(request);

    String tag  = request.getParameter("tag");

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");

    URL url = new URL("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=$python&site=stackoverflow");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String kek;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((kek = in.readLine())!= null ){
        sb.append(Arrays.toString(kek.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }
    in.close();

    pageVariables.put("result", sb);
    
    if (tag == null || tag.isEmpty()) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    }
    else {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
    pageVariables.put("tag", tag == null ? "" : tag);

    response.getWriter().println(PageGenerator.instance().getPage("page.html", pageVariables));
}
```